# How to parse error and status message from serialize()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, json

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //  ...

    $('form').submit(function() {

    // ...

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        data: $(this).serialize(),

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        $('div#create_result').text(
            "responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText +
            ", textStatus: " + textStatus +
            ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);


        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        }, // error 

        success: function(result){
        if (result.error) { // script returned error
            $('div#create_result').text("result.error: " + result.error);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        } // if
        else { // perl script says everything is okay
            $('div#create_result').text(
            "result.success: " + result.success +
            ", result.userid: " + result.userid);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("success");
        } //else
        } // success
    }); // ajax

    $('div#create_result').fadeIn();
    return false;

    });
});
```

which always gives error messages, if it was successful.

Example:

```
responseText: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 {"success" : "Activity created", "Activity number" : "38"}, textStatus: parsererror, errorThrown: SyntaxError: JSON.parse
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

**Update**:

Here is how I make the JSON strings in the server-side Perl script.

```
...
$json = qq{{"error" : "Owner $owner doesn't exist"}};

...
$json = qq{{"success" : "Activity created", "Activity number" : "$id"}};
...

print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
parseError,
SyntaxError: JSON.parse
```

Your response JSON is not acceptable to the parser, it might be malformed. Your posted `responseText` has headers in it, those should NOT be present.:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 {"success" : "Activity created", "Activity number" : "38"}
```

Comment: I have now included the JSON string. Is it correct, that I use `success: function(result){` or should that be `success: function(data){` ?

Comment: You may name the parameter in your function anything that you like (as long as it's not a reserved keyword!) - data or result are both fine. Please note my updated answer, the problem seems to be that you have headers in your JSON response.

Comment: So `success: function(result){` means that I create an object called `result`? I would have expected that `data: $(this).serialize(),` returned an object? This is my first WebApp, so I am very new at this.

Comment: @Sandra: Have you tried putting a new line after your headers, just before the data starts?

Comment: @Sandra They both return objects. Making an ajax request is by default, an asynchronous operation. `serialize()` will return the contents of your `<form>` in a format suitable for submission. The request will happen asynchronously. On completion, your `success` or `error` function will get invoked by jQuery and passed a new object which corresponds to the response.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding So the object names that the functions return are not important, as JQuery takes care of all data travel?

Comment: @Sandra Yes, that's pretty much it. You just need to make sure you're not using conflicting names or keywords (for example, you shouldn't name variables `if, else, super` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [Perl's JSON module](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON/), which handles serialization and parsing for you. There is an XS backend (for speed), as well as a PP (Pure Perl) backend.